# Quickly accessing files in a 'project'

Tags: emacs

I'm looking for a way to quickly open files in my project's source tree. What I've been doing so far is adding files to the file-name-cache like so:

```
(file-cache-add-directory-recursively (concat project-root "some/sub/folder") ".*\\.\\(py\\)$")
```

after which I can use anything-for-files to access any file in the source tree with about 4 keystrokes.

Unfortunately, this solution started falling over today. I've added another folder to the cache and emacs has started running out of memory. What's weird is that this folder contains less than 25% of files I'm adding, and yet emacs memory use goes up from 20mb to 400mb on adding just this folder. The total number of files is around 2000, so this memory use seems very high. Presumably I'm abusing the file cache.

Anyway, what do other people do for this? I like this solution for its simplicity and speed; I've looked at some of the many, many project management packages for emacs and none of them really grabbed me...

Thanks in advance!

Simon

Comment: (Pointing out the obvious) The number of files doesn't matter as much as the *size* of the files.  The question is, why do you want the files to be loaded into Emacs?  Are you really editing 500 files (25% of 2000)?

Comment: Reading the doc and testing here prove me that the *size* of the files do not matter, only their *number*, because file-cache do cache their names, not their contents.

Comment: Indeed - Trey, I'm not opening the files as buffers, merely creating a list of filenames that makes finding files more convenient. At the end of the day I want to be able to hit C-blah, type a few letters from the name of a file somewhere in my project, hit return and open that file.

Isn't this what file-cache is for?

Comment: Apologies, I didn't understand how file-cache worked.  I now do.  However, I just opened an `emacs -q`, and did `M-x file-cache-add-subdirectory` on a directory with 7800 files, and memory usage went up by a whopping 2MB.

Comment: Mm, I think this might be a win32 thing. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Testing here give me no problem with some 50000 file (well, I had to say that I had to wait some time, but Emacs only use 48 mB when it finished), You seem to have been hit by some bug you should probably report.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I've now tried the same folder on Emacs 23.1 with win32, cygwin and linux, all with emacs -q, and they all cause memory to spike quite high. The difference is that, under linux, it comes down again whereas under win32 it stays high, even after forcing a garbage collect.

Anyway, it's good to know that:
a) My approach isn't completely insane and it works for other people.
b) The problem I'm hitting is probably a bug. 

Thanks for the help!

Simon

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you take a look at this [article](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FindFileInProject). I have to support Trey's comment - I don't think your approach is very good at the moment.

Comment: Thanks - I'll check out FindFileInProject.